How to make a specific resume' for various positions (especially in view of automated processes)
I am asking and answering this question, because it comes up a lot.
How do you make a resume' for specific positions?
NOTE:  This assumes that you have a position description with a list of qualifications.
This may help you get around automated processes that are doing key-word searches.
I have a US background only.
I am pasting in the answer from this question:
Question on under and over qualified
Please feel free to write another answer, if you think it would help.

I edited for clarity

@JosephDoggie hello. Couple of feedback. 1) its very common on SE for people to DV (or UV) without posting a comment. The vote itself tells you "this answer is low quality or lacks research", or "this is a good, well-written question". So I wouldn't break my head asking people to provide feedback (unfortunate, I know). 2) remember that reputation is just a number, a gamification tool, so don't give it too much importance (yes what matters is helping/getting help, rather than earning points for the sake of it).

and finally, 3) I see that you are asking "How do you make a resume for specific positions?" . The topic of resumes and tailoring them goes wayy wayy back, and has been asked, asked again, answered and answered again many times. I think that's why you may be seeing DV's (I kindly invite you to 'on-hover' on the downvote option, you'll see an informative text and realize that showing no research effort may result in DVs).

oh yeah and, 4) just pasting your answer from another post into this one doesn't quite click on my head. You didn't even edit it or "tailor" your answer (pun intended). Cross-posting is not encouraged across the network. If one answer fits into two different questions either those questions are the same in principle, or one of those answers is wrong.

People have suggested to make a specific resume' for various positions.
One way to tailor a resume' for a specific position is to do the following:
Copy & paste all of the job requirements into a section in your resume' (e.g. Qualifications):
Then just delete out what isn't true about you.
Example:
C#, JAVA, SQL, HTML

If you didn't know JAVA (for example),
then just edit so it says:
C#, SQL, HTML

This may help you get around automated processes that are doing key-word searches.
I have a US background only.
This method has enabled me to go to many interviews.
My own resume' is much longer than most people would recommend, but it's got me many a job.
Every situation is different, but this is a practical example for you.

I have not voted yet, but I guess this is supposed to get you past automated processes? Because it would look just weird in my CV and don't do anything for me because we don't use such processes where I live. If this is to overcome shortcomings of automated processes, maybe spell that out and add a country where it applies?
